# Using XCODE Application Loader for Testflight Distribution

Tags: xcode, application-loader

Can we use Application Loader to upload app to Itunes Connect to only distribute Via Testflight Or it is only for appstore approval submission to release

The common process via archive upload is not working. Giving error again and again for server busy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Application Loader for sure to upload your IPA binary to iTunes and then share it for internal testing over TestFlight.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the below screen shot from itunes connect is self-explanatory. 
[image]